# Criar condicional com contador em uma coluna

Tags: r

Tenho uma base que preciso saber qual número é maior que 100, porém se tiver uma sequência de valores maiores do que 100 preciso que a coluna acumule o valor de 1 em 1, adicionei uma figura de output de como deveria ficar.

```
base::set.seed(400)
a <- base::round(stats::runif(30, min = 50, max = 300),2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema pode ser resolvido com um truque `diff/cumsum`, que dá segmentos do vetor `a` que cumprem a condição, seguido de `ave/seq_along`, para dar as sequências de inteiros. E para por os zeros nos sítios certos, multiplica-se esse resultado pela condição `f`.

```
f <- a > 100
g <- cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(f) != 0))
b <- ave(g, g, FUN = seq_along)
res <- cbind(a, b = b * f)

head(res, 15)
#           a b
# [1,]  87.49 0
# [2,]  96.35 0
# [3,] 232.70 1
# [4,] 141.15 2
# [5,] 282.40 3
# [6,] 150.45 4
# [7,] 111.85 5
# [8,] 175.59 6
# [9,] 118.41 7
#[10,] 122.31 8
#[11,]  72.02 0
#[12,] 195.78 1
#[13,] 251.33 2
#[14,] 204.64 3
#[15,] 241.09 4
```